# importar csv a python SIN usar rutas absolutas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Explico paso por paso.

- Creo un repo en github con readme y gitignoreVScode.
- Creo una carpeta vacia en mi escritorio a la que llamo x y dentro otra a la que llamo x1 también vacía.
- Navego a través de la terminal hasta x2 y hago git clone de mi repo.ahi se crea otra carpeta que se llama Sharkattack.
- Creo dos directorios dentro de Shark... input y output
- Me descargo un csv de kaggle.
- Copio el csv en input.
- Abro vscode y me voy a gitignore escribo el nombre del csv.
- Desde output abro un jupyter notebook,e importo pandas y otros modulos.

Cuando intento abrir el csv con pandas no me deja.¿Por qué?

Mi codigo`df = pd.read_csv('input/attacks.csv', encoding='cp-1252')`

Me da el siguiente error:
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input/attacks.csv'**

¿Qué está pasando?

Comment: La ruta relativa debe ser `'../input/attacks.csv'` si `input` y `output` están en el mismo directorio y `output` es el directorio de trabajo del script... `'input/attacks.csv'` como es lógico busca la carpeta `input` en el mismo directorio.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias,ha funcionado!!entiendo que los dos puntos es para ir hacia atras como en la terminal??No me han explicado muy bien esto podrías hacerme un breve resumen porfavor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) que une uno o más componentes de ruta de format inteligente:

```
excel = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "ejemplo.xlsx")
```

Comment: podrias explicar un poco porque esto soluciona el problema?? tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad.. mira por favor [answer]